# ReactDOM is not rendering the React component into HTML

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I've been following a React guide which goes through setting up webpack and babel in my repo. I created a react element which will simply print out "Hello World", and then I use the ReactDOM.render method to add this element into the index.html file, but for some reason it's not being added in.

Here is my Index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

export default class App extends React.component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
              Hello World
            </div>
        )
    }
};
//////EDITED OUT <button /> for <App />
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

My index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="root"></div>
```

My webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./App/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
        ]
     },
     plugins: [
          new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
              template: 'App/index.html'
          })
      ]
}
```

My index.css:

```
body {
  background: red;
}
```

My .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

I've checked the dev console on my browser and it simply isn't showing the  component enclosed inside the  component in index.html file. Is there something additional I need for ReactDOM to push my react element into the DOM?

I've looked at others similar questions on stack but their problems ended up existing because of a typo, I've strained my eyes looking over my code and can't find any typos. I think there may be a step in the installation that I've skipped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to render `<App />` not `<button />`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

export default class App extends React.component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
              Hello World
            </div>
        )
    }
};
document.createelement("LI").appendChild(document.createTextNode("Water"));
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

You also need to output that

> /dist/bundle.js

in `index.html`

like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Whoops, I added that in when I was testing to see if ReactDOM could render any element, turns out it can't. The problem still persists when I change it to <App />

Comment: Ok and what script tag you have included on your page? I dont see any in index.html. I updated my answer for that as well.

Comment: The dev console shows the HTML as: <body><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></body>. I think the script tag appeared because of webpack, I'm not sure

Comment: I tried adding in a script tag inside the root div tags in html, as <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>. Still the react component doesn't appear

Comment: Webpacks output is under `/dist`. so you need (whatever your root is) `/dist/bundle.js`

Comment: so I've update my script tag from <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script> to <script type="text/babel" src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>. The components are still not rendering